# Is an object accessible if not assigned to any variable?

Tags: perl, oop, object

While I was working on a Perl script, a question arose just for curiosity. I noticed that no warning or error appears when I create an object without assigning it to any variable (scalar/array/hash).

For example:

```perl
Person->new ('Sebastian', 'Vettel', 30);
```

An MCVE is as follows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Person;
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {
    FirstName => shift,
    LastName  => shift,
    Age       => shift,
  };
  print "Created a Person object: $self->{FirstName} ",
        "$self->{LastName} ($self->{Age})\n";
  bless  $self, $class;
  return $self;
}

Person->new ('Sebastian', 'Vettel', 30);
```

The output:

> Created a Person object: Sebastian Vettel (30)

My question is that. Is there a way to access the created object?

Comment: Add `sub DESTROY { print "Destroyed\n"; }` to the package and `<>;` after `Person->new` and see for yourself.

Comment: @ikegami I tried and saw. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

A call to `Person->new` is under the hood resolves as this:

```
Person::new('Person', 'Sebastian', 'Vettel', 30);
```

Functions in Perl always return scalar values. Sometimes there is an `undef`, and sometimes the number of scalars is zero (which is an empty list). If you assign those values to a variable, or make the function call inside something else that expects an expression, the values become accessible.

```
my $foo = frobnicate();
print frobnicate();
```

Perl has a warning that tells you if you use an expression in a place where it's return value is not useful.

Consider this example.

```
use warnings;
4;
```

This will give you a warning.

> Useless use of a constant (4) in void context at ...

But for a function call, Perl doesn't really know if there will be a return value, so it cannot warn about that. Sometimes function return something for convenience, like `open`, where you opt to ignore the return value, or you could use it for error checking. But ultimately, Perl doesn't know if you meant to do that.

```
Person->new;
```

The return value of that function call is simply discarded in *void context*, and Perl doesn't complain, because there is no reason to assume this was a mistake.

You cannot access this object, it gets created and then thrown away.

---

The only exception is if it's at the end of a sub, where Perl implicitly returns the return value of the last statement of the block, which makes things like this possible.

```
sub build { Foo->new }
```

But that's not something you need to concern yourself with in this context.